# How can I tell if my meth is pure?

Tags: payday-3

On the Cook Off heist, once a batch is done, Shade says something to the effect of "the purity will increase if you let it cook a little longer, but don't let it sit for too long". How can I tell when the meth is pure?

Comment: HNQ title, here we go!

Comment: This is a Payday 2 mission right? I don't remember Payday 2 having meth "purity" levels.  But I guess it could be a new feature.

Comment: Cook Off was added in update 1.0.2 today. And yes, there's some new elements to the heist in Payday 3.

Comment: When I said _This is a Payday 2 mission right?_ I didn't mean the game Payday 2, just that its a Payday 2 mission in Payday 3 (I saw they added this and one other legacy heist).

Comment: NGL, if you just look at the title, it looks really sus lol

Comment: Another contender for best question.

Comment: Based on random comments on Reddit it seems the meth will turn blue with a puff of smoke when it reaches max purity, and the bag will have white X's on the side(s). Don't have the game to test and haven't watched this heist yet, so IDK anything personally.

Comment: Came here to learn about meth purity and all I found was discussion of a video game :-/s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you let the meth stay on the table (meaning not bagging it yet), it will take about 20/30 seconds for it to become pure, meaning it turns blue. There will also be a short soundeffect when it's done.

When the Meth on the table is blue, quickly bag it up, since leaving it cooking too long will turn it red, meaning it's burned.

When you have it bagged, you can throw the bag on the ground and check if the bag is marked with tape "X"es and if it says "Pick up Pure Meth."

Comment: The blue color HAS to be a reference to _Breaking Bad_ and the trademark blue meth (which was more pure than any other meth on the streets because of Walter White's expertise).  I am wondering if that is what inspired the game devs to denote when the meth has reached its purest form.